# Deleting the bullet from the list deletes character before

Tags: java, html

Editor application reads MSword doc into HTML format. All  lists ( new paragrafs with bullets in a begginging in Word file) are read as

```
“<li>+ contentString+”</li>”
```

On the interface the text is displayed in text area and when user is deleting the bullet from list, caret skips the bullets and delete the character preceding it.

Please help.

Comment: Going to need some more details.  Is this a web application?  If so, I assume you're referring to a WYSIWYG editor like CKEditor or TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0):

In html the bullet symbol is a piece of decoration for the items in the list not the part of list item's text. Therefore it will show up as long as there is an item in the list and cannot be deleted with backspase or del.

You can remove bullets by applying additional css (`list-style: none` will do the work).

Comment: Thank you, LioliQ. 
End user still needs to be able to see those bullets as they were on original word document and to be able to delete\edit them. (from their point of view).

Comment: The best solution I came to is adding a bullet symbol in the beginning of each item's text and applying "list-style: none" to the whole list.